# How to store a result of SQL as an variable and use it in the later SQL commands in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to catch the first day of current month:

```
select date_trunc('month',  (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')::date)
```

and intend to use it in a subsequent SQL command as an variable start_date, like:

```
select * from table where create_time > start_date;
```

How to implement that in PostgreSQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
with start_date as (
    select date_trunc('month', current_date) as start_date
)
select *
from
    t
    cross join
    start_date
where create_time >= start_date
```